# Excel - Pivot to create new column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to reorganize data so it can be more user friendly and display better in some charts i have created. I am trying to convert the below sample data into 3 columns. One would be Fruit, The second would be year and the final one would be the total beside it. Is this possible to do within excel itself. I have tried adjusting my pivots and that but no luck. I have 1000s of products so this layout is the most user friendly way of entering the data but i need it in a different format for the charts.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: What exactly does *"I have tried adjusting my pivots"* mean? The operation you are looking for is called unpivoting. You can do this in under a minute using Power Query. If you're looking for an Excel formula or VBA solution, let us know by editing your post and adding the appropriate tag(s).